# Do wasps and yellow jackets leave pheremones that attract them to return to old nests?

Tags: entomology

I decided to ask this question based on the following question a user posted on DIY.

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16965/dealing-with-a-wasp-nest

According to the user quoting his local pest control company:

> I called a exterminator (Terminix, actually), and they tried to push a year-long maintenance contract on me, and claimed that wasps leave pheremones, and if you don't continually kill them off, they will keep coming back.
>
> In my own research, there is no note of this particular wasp behaviour on wikipedia, and I have actually found a lot of insect-control websites that specifically say wasps don't nest in the same place every year. This makes me think that Terminix may be stringing me along a bit.

I have in turn found the following claim by another pest control company:

http://www.gemtekpestcontrol.com/pests-wasps

> Maintenance Plans Take Away the Sting of Being Stung
>
> This is an integral part of effective pest management because wasps and yellowjackets leave behind pheromones on their nests, which increases the likelihood of a re-infestation.

After reading the OP's question, I was curious myself because I was told the same thing by an exterminator when a wasp nest formed inside my attic from a hole in the soffit.  I also could not find this claim outside of Pest Control websites.

It certainly seems like a plausible claim, as I habitually get 5 to 6 wasp nests per year and they usually always form in the same few places, but that may be because they are cozy little corners and near large flowering plants.

Comment: Anecdotal data: i had a wasp nest build up in the same spot in my Brighthouse box 3 times. Maybe its just a very nice spot to build a nest, but maybe they leave that homy smell behind ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The the factors that determine nest site location (for honey bees these are well understood, less so for wasps, though things like protection, height off ground, etc. clearly play a part) are the primary reason wasp colonies appear in the same sites year after year. On shorter time scales (for example right after removing a nest) navigational cause will cause surviving nestmates to reappear in the location of the nest. In neither case (and especially in the former) do pheromones play a big role.

However, like honey bees, some wasps do leave a ["footprint" pheromone](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003347269901225) on heavily trafficked areas around the entrances to their nests, which attracts returning *foragers*, and which may linger and continue to attract the interest of wasps (of any nest) for a time after a nest has been removed. It is unclear however whether it would attract a wasp *founding* a new nest, since an existing nest would be of no interest to them (quite the opposite, actually).

In short, it's unlikely that pheromones are responsible for the reappearance of a nest in an a previously occupied location; but doing something to clean up or mask  any odors left behind after the removal of a nest may help reduce visits by inquisitive foragers.

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out answer, but I am sure you know how the mods here will jump on you if you don't cite sources.